# How do I hide and show form at a specific time in C#?

Tags: c#, timer, callback, alert

I am writing a small application for reminders. For this, I got great help from a similar question and answer on Stack Overflow. I used the code mentioned by Thunder [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297109/how-do-i-generate-an-alert-at-a-specific-time-in-c).

The relevant code is:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.TimerCallback callback = new            System.Threading.TimerCallback(ProcessTimerEvent);
        var dt =    new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day   , 10, 0, 0);

        if (DateTime.Now < dt)
        {
            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null, dt - DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
        this.Hide(); // This line works... Form hides itself
        }

    }

    private void ProcessTimerEvent(object obj)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Hi Its Time");
        this.Show();  //This line does not work. Form gets disposed off instead of show
    }
```

My problem: I get everything as mentioned in that answer (including MessageBox). However, if I try to hide the form when a callback is made and show it once again instead of `MessageBox.Show("Hi Its Time")` it does not work. See my comments on each line. I don't understand why the form gets disposed.

```
this.Visible() // does not work and disposed off the same way
```

Also tried to move the form out of screen by changing its location property. On return, bring back to its original location but this also does not work. What can I do to hide & show the form on return ?

Comment: I am not getting your code..what it does exactly..?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code where you create the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're having a cross thread issue. Your callback should look like this:

```
private void ProcessTimerEvent(object obj)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<object>(this.ProcessTimerEvent), obj);
    }
    else
    {
         this.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or rather use System.Windows.Forms.Timer that uses the synchronisation  context of the form on each callback.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and found that your code is getting this error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

You just have to change `ProcessTimerEvent` function to this:

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action<object>(ProcessTimerEvent), obj);

    // To wait for the thread to complete before continuing.
    this.Invoke(new Action<object>(ProcessTimerEvent), obj);
}
else
{
    this.Show();
}
```

Comment: Why do you suggest a double invoke? Your comment of "To wait for the thread to complete before continuing." before the Invoke call is not correct.