# windows service running at specfic time does run next day

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services, timespan

i have a windows service set to run at certain times, it runs first time but i cant seem to work out how to tell it to run the next day when it gets to end of times..

this is what i am trying...

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        log.Info("Info - Service Start");
        string timeToRunStr = "17:11";
        var timeStrArray = timeToRunStr.Split(';');
        foreach (var strTime in timeStrArray)
        {
            timeToRun.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(strTime));
        }
        ResetTimer();
    }

    void ResetTimer()
    {
        log.Info("Info - Reset Timer");
        try
        {
            TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            TimeSpan nextRunTime = timeToRun[0];
            foreach (TimeSpan runTime in timeToRun)
            {
                if (currentTime < runTime)
                {
                    nextRunTime = runTime;
                    // log.Info("Info - in loop");
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    TimeSpan test = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 16, 51, 0).Subtract(DateTime.Now);
                    nextRunTime = test;
                }
            }
            _timer = new Timer((nextRunTime - currentTime).TotalSeconds * 1000);
            log.Info("Info - Timer : " + (nextRunTime - currentTime).TotalSeconds * 1000);
            log.Info("Info - nextRuntime : " + nextRunTime);
            log.Info("Info - currentTime : " + currentTime);
            _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            _timer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("This is my timer error - ", ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why cook all that logic into a Windows Service when a simple console application + Task Scheduler would work out of the box?

Comment: theres other stuff that happens, i just need to workout the failure of this

Comment: some how have to add 24 hours to the test time span im guessing

Comment: Yeah, you need to start the loop over.

Comment: that wont make it go to the next day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out these alternatives: :
[DateTime of next 3am occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1142638/47733)

Control activities with a timer, see model:

```
class Program
{
    static void my_task(Object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("task being performed.");
    }

    static TimerCallback timerDelegate;
    static Timer timer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime today = now.Date.AddHours(12);
        DateTime next = now <= today ? today : today.AddDays(1);

        timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(my_task);

        //                                     hence the first         after the next       
        timer = new Timer(timerDelegate, null, next - DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i integrate that with my way